# How is loss calculated in truncated BPTT, for a many to one problem?

Tags: lstm, rnn, backpropagation

In many resources I refered to such as Justin Johnson's Lecture 12 on RNN, truncated BPTT is explained as the process of feedforward and backpropagate for smaller chunks of the sequence. These explanations says loss is calculated for each chunk and the last hidden state from the previous chunk is used as the initial hidden state for the next chunk.

But in a many to one problem when there is a target available only at the last time step, how is loss calculated for the chunks? Or how truncated BPTT works in such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your problem it only makes sense to compute the result at the very end of the sequence, then the loss can only be computed at the batch containing the end of the sequence. I guess this gets more complicated if each sequence has a different length.

However, in many-to-one problems, it normally makes sense to compute the result at every time step. For instance, in time series forecasting or in language modeling, the inputs are the previous time steps and the output is the prediction for the next time step, and it makes sense to generate a result (i.e. a prediction for the next time step) at every time step and therefore compute the loss combining the errors of the outputs at each time step in each batch.

Comment: Yes it makes sense now. It is not possible to do a truncated BPTT  for a many to one problem like semantic classification where input is sequence of tokens and output is a label indicating the semantic class